# How to add two values of the same key if there are more than two values in that key itself?

Tags: python, dictionary

so i have a dictionary:

```
a={'price':[1,2,3],'code':['abc','abc','def']}
```

I need to add the first two values of the key 'price' and store it in a variable.
How can i do that?

basically what i want to do is add **1 and 2** not 3 in the key 'price'.

Comment: a['price'] = a['price'][:2]

Answer (score 0):

The following should give what you want:

```
new_var=a['price'][0]+a['price'][0]


 or

new_var=sum(a['price'][:2])
```